# C++: What type is the data in text files?

Tags: c++, fstream, ofstream

I can make a ofstream object to a textfile like this

`ofstream obj("file.txt")`

Then i can go ahead and send to it an `int c=5`

`obj << c;`

When i send `c` to the text file, What type of data does it get stored as?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Files are streams of bytes. There is no data typing in the file. When you read that information back from the file you're responsible for knowing what data type to expect.

Comment: ... and doing validation and verification as well.

Comment: Technically, Files are sources of data not stream of bytes.

Comment: in the eyes of C++ it is a stream of bytes

Comment: @MohamedAhmedNabil - they are sources or sinks; both C and C++ view them as streams of bytes. Hence the name "iostream".

Comment: Text files are data sources, The file stream is what sends the data to them, But, it is common to say that the file itself is the stream, Like you might say you sort a box containing papers,  In reality there is nothing as sorting a box, you are sorting the paper inside it

Comment: One more question, You said there is no type. Meaning that everything i send is stored as text?

Comment: @MohamedAhmedNabil - everything is stored as whatever the underlying file system uses for storage, typically 8-bit bytes. If you use stream inserters, the data will be converted to bytes that represent characters. You can also write raw data, which will be stored as bytes without transformation (other than whatever transformations are done for text if the file was opened as a text file, typically just newline characters).

Comment: But basically writing to a text file,  stores all values as text

Answer (score 0):

Several factors determine the type of data that your `iostream` class considers.

The constructor establishes whether the stream operates on **text** or **binary** data.

- `ofstream obj("file.txt")` will consider streamed data to be text.
- `ofstream obj("file.txt", ios_base::binary)` will consider streamed
  data to be binary.

You are using text.  Note that the representation of "text" can be interpreted differently by different operating systems.

You can also affect the interpretation of stream data by sending the `iostream` `smanip` types, such as what would be returned by `setw(int)`.

Comment: However, opening a file as text or as binary only affects how certain byte values get transformed when they are stored or read (on Unix there are no byte values that get transformed). You can write raw bytes to a text file and write formatted text to a binary file.

Comment: @PeteBecker Good point.  I am interpreting the question as being inclusive of how bytes may be transformed as they're stored.

Answer (score 0):

Text file streams are those where we do not include the ios::binary flag in their opening mode. These files are designed to store text and thus all values that we input or output from/to them  which do not necessarily correspond to their literal binary value.

In short, Non-binary files are known as text files.